# memory efficient way to create a column that indicates a unique combination of values from a set of columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, dask

I want to find a more efficient way (in terms of peak memory usage and possibly time) to do the work of panda's `groupby.ngroup` so that I don't run into memory issues when working with large datasets (I provide reasons for why this column is useful to me below). Take this example with a small dataset. I can accomplish this task easily using `groupby.ngroup`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(
        [[0, 1, 92],
        [0, 0, 39],
        [0, 0, 32],
        [1, 0, 44],
        [1, 1, 50],
        [0, 1, 11],
        [0, 0, 14]]), columns=['male', 'edu', 'wage'])

df['group_id'] = df.groupby(['male', 'edu']).ngroup()
df
   male  edu  wage  group_id
0     0    1    92         1
1     0    0    39         0
2     0    0    32         0
3     1    0    44         2
4     1    1    50         3
5     0    1    11         1
6     0    0    14         0
```

But when I start using larger datasets, the memory usage and computation time explodes and the memory usage in the groupby as a ratio over the memory usage of the dataframe increases almost three-fold for `N=100,000,000` as compared to `N=100,000`. See below.

```
from memory_profiler import memory_usage
import time

N_values = [10**k for k in range(4, 9)]

stats = pd.DataFrame(index=N_values, dtype=float, columns=['time', 'basemem', 'groupby_mem'])

for N in N_values:
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        np.hstack([np.random.randint(0, 2, (N, 2)), np.random.normal(5, 1, (N, 1))]),
        columns=['male', 'edu', 'wage']        
    )

    def groupby_ngroup():
        df.groupby(['male', 'edu']).ngroup()

    def foo():
        pass

    basemem = max(memory_usage(proc=foo))

    tic = time.time()
    mem = max(memory_usage(proc=groupby_ngroup))
    toc = time.time() - tic

    stats.loc[N, 'basemem'] = basemem
    stats.loc[N, 'groupby_mem'] = mem
    stats.loc[N, 'time'] = toc

stats['mem_ratio'] = stats.eval('groupby_mem/basemem')
stats
               time      basemem  groupby_mem  mem_ratio
10000      0.037834   104.781250   105.359375   1.005517
100000     0.051785   108.187500   113.125000   1.045638
1000000    0.143642   128.156250   182.437500   1.423555
10000000   0.644650   334.148438   820.183594   2.454549
100000000  6.074531  2422.585938  7095.437500   2.928869
```

Why am I interested in this group identifier? Because I want to create columns that utilize pandas' `groupby` functions such as `groupby.mean` using the `.map` method as opposed to `groupby.transform` which takes a lot of memory and time. Furthermore, the `.map` approach can be used with `dask` dataframes as `dask` currently doesn't support `.transform`.  With a column for `"group_id"` I can simply do `means = df.groupby(['group_id'])['wage'].mean()` and `df['mean_wage'] = df['group_id'].map(means)` to do the work of `transform`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a groupby where groupby variables are of unknown pattern, it seems that `groupby.ngroup` may be as good as it gets. But if your groupby variables are all categorical, e.g., take values `0,1,2,3....`, then we can take inspiration from the solution given by `@saurjog`.

To generate the group ID, we can build a numerical expression that evaluates a special sum of the groupby variables. Consider the following functions

```py
def gen_groupby_numexpr(cols, numcats):
    txt = [cols[0]]

    k = numcats[0]

    for c,k_ in zip(cols[1:], numcats[1:]):

        txt.append('{}*{}'.format(k, c))

        k = k*k_

    return ' + '.join(txt)

def ngroup_cat(df, by, numcats):
    '''
    by : list
        the categorical (0,1,2,3...) groupby column names
    numcats : list
        the number of unique values for each column in "by"
    '''
    expr = gen_groupby_numexpr(by, numcats)

    return df.eval(expr)
```

The function `gen_groupby_numexpr` generates the numerical expression and `ngroup_cat` generates the group id for the groupby variables in `by` with unique value counts `numcats`. Thus, consider the following dataset that matches our use case. It contains 3 categorical variables we will use to form the groupby, two of which take values in `{0,1}` and one takes values in `{0,1,2}`.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.hstack([np.random.randint(0, 2, (100, 2)), 
                              np.random.randint(0, 3, (100, 1)), 
                              np.random.randint(0, 20, (100, 1))]), 
    columns=['male', 'mar', 'edu', 'wage'])
```

If we generate the numerical expression we get:

```
'male + 2*mar + 4*edu'
```

Putting this altogether, we can generate the group id with

```
df2['group_id'] = ngroup_cat(df2, ['male', 'mar', 'edu'], [2, 2, 3])
```

from which we get `2*2*3=12` unique group IDs:

```
df2[['male', 'mar', 'edu', 'group_id']].drop_duplicates().sort_values(['group_id'])
    male  mar  edu  group_id
1      0    0    0         0
13     1    0    0         1
8      0    1    0         2
10     1    1    0         3
4      0    0    1         4
12     1    0    1         5
2      0    1    1         6
6      1    1    1         7
7      0    0    2         8
5      1    0    2         9
44     0    1    2        10
0      1    1    2        11
```

When I bench mark the solution above against `groupby.ngroup` it runs nearly 3 times faster on a dataset of `N=10,000,000` and uses significantly less additional memory.

Now we can estimate these groupby means and then map them back to the whole dataframe to do the work of transform. I compute some benchmarks with mixed results on whether using `transform` or `groupby` then `map` is faster and less memory intensive. If you are computing means for groups of many variables then I think the latter is more efficient. Further, the latter can also be done in `dask` where `transform` is not yet supported.

Answer (score 1):

How about not using `ngroup`, and instead writing our own function to create `group_id` column?

Here is a code snippet that seems to give a slightly better performance:

```
from memory_profiler import memory_usage
import time
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

N_values = [10**k for k in range(4, 9)]

stats = pd.DataFrame(index=N_values, dtype=float, columns=['time', 'basemem', 'groupby_mem'])

for N in N_values:
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        np.hstack([np.random.randint(0, 2, (N, 2)), np.random.normal(5, 1, (N, 1))]),
        columns=['male', 'edu', 'wage']        
    )

    def groupby_ngroup():
        #df.groupby(['male', 'edu']).ngroup()
        df['group_id'] = 2*df.male + df.edu

    def foo():
        pass

    basemem = max(memory_usage(proc=foo))

    tic = time.time()
    mem = max(memory_usage(proc=groupby_ngroup))
    toc = time.time() - tic

    stats.loc[N, 'basemem'] = basemem
    stats.loc[N, 'groupby_mem'] = mem
    stats.loc[N, 'time'] = toc

stats['mem_ratio'] = stats.eval('groupby_mem/basemem')
stats


            time        basemem     groupby_mem mem_ratio
10000       0.117921    2370.792969 79.761719   0.033643
100000      0.026921    84.265625   84.324219   1.000695
1000000     0.067960    130.101562  130.101562  1.000000
10000000    0.220024    308.378906  536.140625  1.738577
100000000   0.751135    2367.187500 3651.171875 1.542409
```

Essentially, we use the fact that the columns are numerical and treat them as binary numbers. The `group_id`s shall be the decimal equivalents.

Scaling it for three columns gives a similar result. For that, replace the dataframe initialization to the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
        np.hstack([np.random.randint(0, 2, (N, 3)), np.random.normal(5, 1, (N, 1))]),
        columns=['male', 'edu','random1', 'wage']        
    )
```

and group_id function to:

```
def groupby_ngroup():
        df['group_id'] = 4*df.male + 2*df.edu + df.random1
```

Following are the results of that test:

```
            time        basemem     groupby_mem mem_ratio
10000       0.050006    78.906250   78.980469   1.000941
100000      0.033699    85.007812   86.339844   1.015670
1000000     0.066184    147.378906  147.378906  1.000000
10000000    0.322198    422.039062  691.179688  1.637715
100000000   1.233054    3167.921875 5183.183594 1.636146
```

Comment: I like this solution a lot. I had been thinking of a solution for a general set of columns with discrete support, but perhaps there is no better general solution and I should think instead of preprocessing data to get it into the form of pure categoricals, taking values `0,1,2,...` and then using your approach. So, in general, if `C` denotes my `N` group by columns, and `K` the number of unique values in each column, I can in general use `C_0 + (K_0)*C_1 + (K_0*K_1)*C_2 + ... + (K_0*K_1*....*K_{N-1})C_N`?

Comment: @jtorca, apologies for the late reply. The multiplier depends on the maximum number of categories for all the columns. Say, `C_1, ..., C_N` are the group_by columns. Then `K = max(num_categories(C_1, ..., C_N))`. This is because we are assuming values in every column to be a representation in a number system which has a base `K`. Let's say we have 3 columns. C_1 and C_2 take values [0,1] and C_3 takes values [0,1,2]. Here, `K = 3`. and the equivalent group_id will be calculated as `(3**2)C_1 + (3**1)C_2 + (3**0)C_3`. Does this make sense?

Comment: Oh, I see. That definitely works. I based my suggestion taking your original proposal as inspiration but I guess I didn't match it quite right. Though I think my first guess also happens to get unique categories and has the advantage of creating contiguous integer valued ids for the groups, e.g., `0,1,2,3,...`.

Comment: @jtorca yes, I think your solution works too and perhaps efficiently than mine.

Answer (score 0):

Let us try using `hash`

```
list(map(hash,df.to_records().tolist()))
[4686582722376372986, 3632587615391525059, 2578593961740479157, -48845846747569345, 2044051356115000853, -583388452461625474, -1637380652526859201]
```

Comment: It appears that this method performs worse in both time and memory usage than `ngroup`.